# regex - how to select a word that has a '-' in it?

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am learning Regular Expressions, so apologies for a simple question.

I want to select the words that have a '-' (minus sign) in it but not at the beginning and not at the end of the word

I tried (using findall):

```
r'\b-\b'
```

for

```
str = 'word semi-column peace'
```

but, of course got only:

```
['-']
```

Thank you!

Comment: I good place to test a regex in real without having to run the code is http://pythex.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a '-' (minus sign) in it but **not at the beginning** and **not at the end** of the word

Since `"-"` is **not** a word character, you can't use word boundaries (`\b`) to prevent a match from words with hyphens at the beggining or end. A string like `"-not-wanted-"` will match both `\b\w+-\w+\b` and `\w+-\w+`.

---

We need to add an extra condition before and after the word:

- Before: `(?<![-\w])` not preceded by either a hyphen nor a word character.
- After: `(?![-\w])` not followed by either a hyphen nor a word character.

Also, a word may have more than 1 hyphen in it, and we need to allow it. What we can do here is repeat the last part of the word ("hyphen and word characters") once or more:

- `\w+(?:-\w+)+` matches:

  - `\w+` one or more word characters
  - `(?:-\w+)+` a hyphen and one or more word characters, and also allows this last part to repeat.

**Regex:**

```
(?<![-\w])\w+(?:-\w+)+(?![-\w])
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pH1vX0/2)</kbd>

**Code:**

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<![-\w])\w+(?:-\w+)+(?![-\w])')
text = "-abc word semi-column peace -not-wanted- one-word dont-match- multi-hyphenated-word"

result = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/kjjdIp)</kbd>

Comment: As any regular expression should be :)

Comment: what will take place if there is an expression? For instance, instead of "semi-column" there is "2.0 - 3 -alpha"  will this still work (it will disregard the expression)?

Comment: It won't match it, because there are spaces around the hyphens, but it will match if you remove the spaces [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pH1vX0/3). If you want to exclude digits, change the main `\w`'s to `[a-zA-Z]` [new regex](https://regex101.com/r/pH1vX0/4)

Answer (score 4):

```
str is a built in name, better not to use it for naming

st = 'word semi-column peace'
# \w+ word - \w+ word after - 
print(re.findall(r"\b\w+-\w+\b",st))

['semi-column']
```

Comment: @LetzerWilie - Thank you! What if instead of words there is an expression: "2.2 -3.5-beta"? Will it work as well (meaning, regex will disregard the expression)? Also the definition of words (from what I gathered) can change slightly one regex implementation to another. Is there a way to address that?

Answer (score 4):

What you actually want to do is a regex like this:

```
\w+-\w+
```

What this means is find a alphanumeric character at least once as indicated by the utilization of '+', then find a '-', following by another alphanumeric character at least once, again, as indicated by the '+' again.

Comment: Thank you! great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following regex:

```
>>> st = "word semi-column peace"
>>> print re.findall(r"\S+\-\S+", st)
['semi-column']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: Centering on the hyphen, I match until there is a white space in either direction from the hyphen I also make check to see if the words are surrounded by hyphens (e.g -test-cats-) and if they are I make sure not to include them. The regular expression should also work with findall.

```
st = 'word semi-column peace'
m = re.search(r'([^ | ^-]+-[^ | ^-]+)', st)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Comment: another creative approach! Thank you all!